# Serverless offline not getting route

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

I have a serverless project that I just newly initialized:

`severless.yml`:

```
service: lambda

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: /hello
          method: GET

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

And I run it with `sls offline --port 8080`:

```
Serverless: Starting Offline: dev/us-east-1

Serverless: Routes for hello:
Serverless: GET /hello

Serverless: Offline listening on http://localhost:8080
```

and in my `handler.ts`

```
module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {
  console.log('HIIII')
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
      input: event,
    }),
  };
};
```

I hit up this endpoint on Postman locally and it doesn't seem to work. All I get is some HTML saying `Cannot GET /hello`. I've tried making GET requests to `http://localhost:8080/dev/hello` or `http://localhost:8080/hello` and I still get the same errors. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure? I just copy/pasted every part of your example and `http://localhost:8080/hello` works just fine.

Comment: @Spacebear5000 you mentioned handler.ts, are you sure you are referencing the right js file on the serverless.yml?

Comment: It could be related to your callback. Check whether it is returning something and depending of the tool you use to make the request, it may not recognise the response.

Comment: Most probably you would one need to restart the "serverless offline" command.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build your typescript project before `serverless-offline` can run your code.
You can either create a `tsconfig.json` file and build the project before running `serverless offline start`, or you can use the [serverless-plugin-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-typescript) to do this for you. Just ensure the plugin is declared *above* the `serverless-offline` plugin in your `serverless.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, make sure you are not running something else on that PORT