# "Serverless-offline: route not found." running an AWS Lambda function in offline mode

Tags: javascript, routes, serverless-framework, serverless

This question is pretty much the same as [Serverless offline not getting route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55130796/serverless-offline-not-getting-route), but since that one was not answered I'm asking again. I'm trying to follow this article, https://medium.com/@awesome1888/how-to-use-serverless-locally-with-webpack-and-docker-5e268f71715, on how to deploy a Lambda function with Serverless.

I have a directory with the following structure:

```
> tree -I node_modules
.
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── serverless.yml
├── src
│   ├── handler.js
│   └── index.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

where `serverless.yml` reads

```
service: my-first-lambda

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  region: us-east-1
  stage: dev

functions:
  hello:
    handler: src/handler.main
    events:
      - http:
        path: /hello
        method: any

custom:
  webpack:
    includeModules: true
```

`src/index.js` reads

```
import moment from 'moment';

const handler = async (event, context) => {
  const body = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`Hello, this is your lambda speaking. Today is ${moment().format('dddd')}`)
    }, 2000);
  });
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body,
  };
}

export default handler;
```

`src/handler.js` reads

```
export { default as main } from './index';
```

and `webpack.config.js` reads

```
const path = require("path");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const slsw = require("serverless-webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: "node",
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? "development" : "production",
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    libraryTarget: "commonjs",
    path: path.join(__dirname, ".webpack"),
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
              plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

The problem is when I start up the function in offline mode, it seems to have only one very specific route:

```
> 
npx serverless offline start --region us-east-1 --noTimeout --port 3000 --host 0.0.0.0
Serverless: Bundling with Webpack...
Time: 1203ms
Built at: 08/30/2019 2:35:10 PM
         Asset      Size       Chunks             Chunk Names
src/handler.js  6.81 KiB  src/handler  [emitted]  src/handler
Entrypoint src/handler = src/handler.js
[./src/handler.js] 42 bytes {src/handler} [built]
[./src/index.js] 1.64 KiB {src/handler} [built]
[moment] external "moment" 42 bytes {src/handler} [built]
Serverless: Watching for changes...
Serverless: Starting Offline: dev/us-east-1.

Serverless: Routes for hello:
Serverless: POST /{apiVersion}/functions/my-first-lambda-dev-hello/invocations

Serverless: Offline [HTTP] listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
Serverless: Enter "rp" to replay the last request
```

and if I go to http://localhost:3000/hello, I get this response:

```
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Serverless-offline: route not found.","currentRoute":"get - /hello","existingRoutes":["post - /{apiVersion}/functions/my-first-lambda-dev-hello/invocations"]}
```

Any idea why this is not working? (I've perused https://serverless.com/framework/docs/ but couldn't quickly find an answer).

Answer (score 21):

I had this issue and if anyone comes across it, this [github comment fixed my issue](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/911#issuecomment-606411258).

You can run `$ sls offline start --noPrependStageInUrl` or add the following to your `serverless.yml` file

```yaml
custom:
  serverless-offline:
    noPrependStageInUrl: true
```

According to the comment:

> I had this problem with anything 6+, this was due to the fact that it now defaults to appending the staging name to the url path. To revert to the old way, you need to add --noPrependStageInUrl to the cli or in the serverless file custom: serverless-offline noPrependStageInUrl: true to revert to previous setting. I'm testing it his out but @dherault the functionality is not reflecting what is actually happening in AWS.

I was using `serverless-offline: "6.7.0"` and my `index.handler` was as below:

```js
const serverless = require("serverless-http");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

And my `serverless.yml`

```yml
plugins:
  - serverless-offline

custom:
  serverless-offline:
    noPrependStageInUrl: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-2

functions:
  app:
    handler: src/index.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: "ANY {proxy+}"
```

Apologies this isn't exactly a great answer but hopefully, someone comes across this and it is a solution to their problem.

Answer (score 12):

Looks like you've got a whitespace issue in your `serverless.yml` file.

Try indenting `path` and `method` under the `http` block:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: src/handler.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: /hello
          method: any
```

Answer (score 0):

for setup a quick example using serverless template  :

```
sls create -h
```

output :

```
create ........................ Create new Serverless service
--template / -t .................... Template for the service. Available templates: "aws-clojure-gradle", "aws-clojurescript-gradle", "aws-nodejs", "aws-nodejs-typescript", "aws-alexa-typescript", "aws-nodejs-ecma-script", "aws-python", "aws-python3", "aws-groovy-gradle", "aws-java-maven", "aws-java-gradle", "aws-kotlin-jvm-maven", "aws-kotlin-jvm-gradle", "aws-kotlin-nodejs-gradle", "aws-scala-sbt", "aws-csharp", "aws-fsharp", "aws-go", "aws-go-dep", "aws-go-mod", "aws-ruby", "aws-provided", "azure-nodejs", "cloudflare-workers", "cloudflare-workers-enterprise", "cloudflare-workers-rust", "fn-nodejs", "fn-go", "google-nodejs", "google-python", "google-go", "kubeless-python", "kubeless-nodejs", "openwhisk-java-maven", "openwhisk-nodejs", "openwhisk-php", "openwhisk-python", "openwhisk-ruby", "openwhisk-swift", "spotinst-nodejs", "spotinst-python", "spotinst-ruby", "spotinst-java8", "plugin" and "hello-world"
```

step1: so for generated a new nodejs example with an api :

```
sls create -t aws-nodejs-ecma-script -n service-name-hello-world
```

step2: install serverless-offline :

```
npm install serverless-offline -D
```

step3: in serverless.yml

```
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-offline
```

step4 : start local server

```
serverless offline start -r us-west-1 --stage dev
```

**github Example**

```
git clone https://github.com/ysfmag/aws-serverless-nodejs-example
cd aws-serverless-nodejs-example
yarn 
yarn start
```

**serverless.yml**

to define an api in your serverless framework you need to respect yaml format , and in the path variable you dont need to start with '/hello' just 'hello' will work .

```
functions:
  hello:
  handler: src/handler.main
  events:
    - http:
        path: hello
        method: get
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pointing out that methods above the path behave differently than other way around for all other methods except GET (facepalm):

- route not found:

  ```
  - http:
      method: ANY
      path: /
  - http:
      method: ANY
      path: '{proxy+}'
  ```
- working:

  ```
  - http:
      path: /
      method: ANY
  - http:
      path: '{proxy+}'
      method: ANY
  ```